# How to mark up C# class with attributes to make it XML serializable?

Tags: c#, xml, .net-4.0

So I have a class. I want to make it serializable (into XML and back). I know how to use Xml.Linq to serialize.. but it is serialization via hand - not automated alike protobuf with its `[ProtoContract]` [and other attributes](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Attributes) when I mark up class and get it back and forward serializable.

So I wonder ho waving

```
public class Entries {
    public List<Entry> Entries {get; set;}
}

public class Entry {
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string Path {get; set;}
}
```

get XML like:

```
<entries>
    <entry id="value" path="value"/>
</entries>
```

So how to mark up C# class with attributes to make it XML serializable?

Comment: Can you try http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813

Comment: Well what have you tried, and what research have you done? Searching for "xml serialization" gets lots of hits...

Comment: Refer : http://tech.pro/tutorial/798/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722126/c-sharp-xml-serialization-deserialization

Answer (score 2):

You need to use attributes like `[XmlRoot]` and `[XmlAttribute]` for this. You can specify the XML element names as a parameter on the attributes.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.aspx and the rest of the attributes in the namespace for the attributes you can use.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add attributes to the class and class members that match your XML, for example: -

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("RootNode")] 
public class Example
{
    [XmlElement("Foo")]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Bar")]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```