# what is better .txt or .xml

Tags: xml, file, converters, txt2tags

I have a question, is it better to read char by char from txt file and make changes. Or it is better to convert txt file to xml, and then to make changes in the file?
I have txt file:

```
 Record: 1
 {
      choice = mobileToMobile:{
      subscriberServicesIndicator = 09,
      callIdentificationNumber = 70 CD BE,
      recordSequenceNumber = 40 63 0F,
      typeOfCallingSubscriber = 01,
      callingPartyNumber = 41 27 27 19 66 91, -> needs to be changed to 41 72 72 91 66 19
      calledPartyNumber = 31 27 37 72 73 10,  -> needs to be changed to 31 72 73 27 37 10
      disconnectingParty = callingPartyRelease,
      dateForStartofCharging = 14 0C 01 1F,  -> change from hexadecimal to decimal number
      timeForStartofCharging = 0A 35 00,     -> ...
      timeForStopofCharging = 0A 38 1D,      ->
      chargeableDuration = 00 03 1E,
      interruptionTime = 00 00 00,
      timeFromRegisterSeizureToStartOfCharging = 00 00 07,
      calledSubscriberInitialServingCellID = 02 06 33,
      originForCharging = 00,
      }
  }
Record: 2
{
...... so on
}
```

Comment: XML is rarely the solution to any problem except "how do I get information to this thing that expects XML?" because it adds complexity without providing much flexibility. awk or Perl would make quick work of the problem you've shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do your own thing char by char, you might find that your code isn't optimised and will chow resources like crazy. So in that regard, I would say stay away, unless you really know what you are doing.

With XML there are a bunch of tools (for example XPath) at your disposal to query and update the values. These tools will probably be highly optimised and thus you can use it without worrying about resources for the best possible performance,

Just a side note. The text you provided looks a lot like JSON and that might be a third option to use.

Comment: So it means better to use xml. thank you. I tried to use read char by char, it takes ages to read from file, make changes and write back. What about xml, is it faster?

Comment: XML won't be the fastest option. The fastest would be to load the data into a custom object that you created sitting in memory so that you can manipulate it there and then. Then you can save it back to disk by serializing it and writing it to disk. What would make the XML faster in this case rather than reading from the file, char by char is just that you have better tools at your disposal, which will have been optimised by the devs that built them to give the best possible performance. Also, don't read the contents of the file from disk. Rather load it into memory first, then do what you need

Comment: Also, if you have the record in XML, you can use things like XPath or Linq to XML to read the data - which is very easy and quick to set up. Look at these links http://www.w3schools.com/xquery/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397981(v=vs.90).aspx (Linq to XML which is also called XQuery) and also http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_nodes.asp

Comment: "The fastest would be to load the data into a custom object that you created sitting in memory so that you can manipulate it there.." what do you mean? I should create object and copy all data from xml file, make some changes, and then save back to xml file?

Comment: You have to create a custom object/class with the properties of you want populated from the XML. I am not sure what language you are doing this in, but for eg. in C# you would decorate the custom object with a Serializable/DataContract attribute and then deserialize the xml into the object. Here is a good [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722126/c-sharp-xml-serialization-deserialization). When the object is populated you can do with it what you want, then serialize it back into XML.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in an XML file just for readability, but it's quite the same.
Also, in my opinion it's easier to work with XML reading tools, but maybe it is just me.

Answer (score 0):

A .txt file and a .xml file is actually the same. The file extension just tells something about what's in the file. I would recommend using .xml, so if anyone finds the file, they know what's in there.