# How to access applicationSettings from another class libraries other than my application project

Tags: c#, .net

I write some values in my application project (the WpfApplication1 project in my solution) and  the problem is whether it is possible to retrieve them if and when necessary in a class library like StateModule project.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <section name="WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
        </sectionGroup>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <applicationSettings>
        <WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="a" serializeAs="String">
                <value>b</value>
            </setting>
        </WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
<userSettings>
    <WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings>
    <setting name="b" serializeAs="String">
        <value>c</value>
    </setting>
    </WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
</configuration>
```

I can access the values within my WpfApplication1 project using the following method:

string myStr = Properties.Settings.Default.a;

Since I have already add reference to project StateModule in WpfApplication1, I can't do it the other way round.

Can anyone tell me what I'm supposed to do? Or is these there anything wrong with my design pattern?

Comment: Just do not use Application Settings (even if you may access them indirectly reading sections manually). For this case I would go back to underlying stuff and Config Sections.

Comment: I would maybe define a separate configurationfile, and a corresponding class so that it would be possible to serialize/deserialze, and share that among the projects that need to share configuration. Possibly something like this: [C# Xml Serialization & Deserialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722126/c-sharp-xml-serialization-deserialization)

Comment: What you mean is that where is not short path to do this, am I right? I thought there must be a reason MS came up with applicationSettings since .net 2.0