# Modfiying Xml using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml

```
<PolicyHdr>
 <PolicyHdrData>
  <ID>123</ID>
 </PolicyHdrData>
</PolicyHdr>
<Role>
 <RoleData>
  <DisplayFieldName>Payor</DisplayFieldName>
 </RoleData>
</Role>
<PolicyCovHdr>
 <PolicyCovHdrData>
  <ID>000</ID>
  <PolicyHdrID>123</PolicyHdrID>
 </PolicyCovHdrData>
</PolicyCovHdr>
<Role>
 <RoleData>
  <DisplayFieldName>Insured</DisplayFieldName>
 </RoleData>
</Role>
```

I need to modify this xml such that the PolicyCovHdr comes as child node of PolicyHDr where the ID node under PolicyHdr is equal to the PolicyHdrID under POlicyCovHDr. 
Also the Role Nodes , whenever the DisplayFieldName is Payor it should be child of PolicyHdr and of the DisplayFieldName is Insure it should be the child node of PolicyCovHdr

So the final xml should look something like this:-

```
<PolicyHdr>
     <PolicyHdrData>
      <ID>123</ID> 
      <Role>
       <RoleData>
        <DisplayFieldName>Payor</DisplayFieldName>
       </RoleData>
      </Role>
    </PolicyHdrData>
     <PolicyCovHdr>
     <PolicyCovHdrData>
      <ID>000</ID>
      <PolicyHdrID>123</PolicyHdrID>
      <Role>
        <RoleData>
        <DisplayFieldName>Insured</DisplayFieldName>
        </RoleData>
      </Role>
     </PolicyCovHdrData>
    </PolicyCovHdr>
</PolicyHdr>
```

Could someone help me with some logic which I could use to achieve this xml

Hi sorry I forgot to add my code changes here

```
string xml1 = "<xml><PolicyHdr><PolicyHdrData><ID>123</ID></PolicyHdrData></PolicyHdr><Role><RoleData><DisplayFieldName>Payor</DisplayFieldName></RoleData></Role><PolicyCovHdr><PolicyCovHdrData><ID>000</ID><PolicyHdrID>123</PolicyHdrID></PolicyCovHdrData></PolicyCovHdr><Role><RoleData><DisplayFieldName>Insured</DisplayFieldName></RoleData></Role></xml>";
XmlDocument test = new XmlDocument();

test.LoadXml(xml1);
XmlNodeList polList = test.SelectNodes("//PolicyHdr/PolicyHdrData");
foreach (XmlNode xn in polList)
{
    XmlNode polNode = xn.SelectSingleNode("//PolicyHdr/PolicyHdrData/ID");
    XmlNodeList polCovNodeList = test.SelectNodes("//PolicyCovHdr/PolicyCovHdrData");

    foreach (XmlNode yn in polCovNodeList)
    {
        XmlNode polCovPolNode = yn.SelectSingleNode("//PolicyCovHdr/PolicyCovHdrData/PolicyHdrID");
        if(polNode.InnerText.ToString().Equals(polCovPolNode.InnerText.ToString()))
        {
            xn.AppendChild(yn);
        }
    }

    XmlNodeList polRoleList = test.SelectNodes("//Role/RoleData");
    foreach (XmlNode zn in polRoleList )
    {
        XmlNode RoleNode = zn.SelectSingleNode("//Role/RoleData/DisplayFieldName");
        if(RoleNode.InnerText.ToString().Equals("Payor"))
        {
            xn.AppendChild(zn);
        }

        //Console.WriteLine(RoleNode.InnerText.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine(xn.OuterXml.ToString());
}
```

The problem right now I am facing is the complexity is (n^2) and adding the Role node as child to PolicyCovHdr when DisplayFieldName = Insured.

Right now the output looks like this

```
<PolicyHdrData><ID>123</ID><PolicyCovHdrData><ID>000</ID><PolicyHdrID>123</PolicyHdrID></PolicyCovHdrData><RoleData><DisplayFieldName>Payor</DisplayFieldName></RoleData></PolicyHdrData>
```

I am still thinking of how to add the Role with DisplayFieldname as Insured as well because of the complexity is already very high

Comment: What about trying at first on your own and if you struggle go ahead and ask us then for some help. **You try, i help. You dont try, i dont help.**

Comment: you can use xslt process or deseralize(into an object)/mapping(to another object)/serialize(the final object). But we'll don't do your homework ;) try yourself before

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Another problem with “could someone help me” is that we don't know what you're stuck on. Do you have a C# compiler? You do, but you don't know any C# at all? You know some C# but you're getting an error? What's the error? Or you're not getting an error but not getting the results you expect either? Where's your code? What results do you expect? What are you getting?

Comment: Theoretically you should be able to accomplish your first goal of "moving" the `PolicyCovHdr` elements based on their ID values.  However, what criteria do you use to decide where to move the `Role` elements?  I haven't parsed your code yet, I'm just trying to understand the theory of your problem first.

Comment: The logic is that if the DisplayFieldName = Insured it should be moved as child to PolicyCovHdr and if the DisplayFieldName = Payor it should be child of PolicyHdr

Answer (score -1):

I think that you should use XML Serialization/Deserialization. You can look for example to this question: [C# Xml Serialization & Deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722126/c-sharp-xml-serialization-deserialization)

At first you can create an object with structure of your input XML, than use XML Deserializer to load the data from XML to this object. After that you can work with the instance of an object and ad some conditions to your code which you need.

You can create another objects which will be representing output XML (depends on the structure as you wrote about it) and in if/else code filling the object with the data you need. Structure of XML will be represented by the structure of the object. Finally you can use XML Serializer to create your XML.

There could probably be better solution, but that should also work.

Comment: Actually, this isn't as bad of an idea as some might think.  The objects will be highly coupled with the data, but in this case I don't think that's avoidable.